# Sample of a gzipped file on Azure Datalake

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, azure-data-lake

How do I preview a .gz file on the azure data lake via cli?
Through the portal, I cannot preview a gzipped file.  I have only access to the CLI.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible. Preview does not work with zipped files.